# New files in network folder temporarily not visible on Windows 7 explorer, but can see the folder and its other contents

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Myself and a coworker are having an issue where sometimes we are looking at a network folder, and when we add or create new files into the folder, we cannot see those new files from our Windows 7 EE.  If we log into our Windows 2003 Server VMs, we can see the files on the network folder.  Tab back to Win 7, still cannot see them.  This can go on for up to 30 minutes.

Is this a problem with how Windows 7 explorer.exe handles index caching?  I don't know what else it could be.

Ideally, when I point explorer at a network folder, it should query the contents of that folder and display them.  There should be no reason why it delays my view for up to 30 minutes, while showing the other files (usually just a few) in that same folder.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm having similar problems but with a Windows 2008 r2 file server.

Answer (score 0):

There could be an issue with the Directory cache. By setting up the "DirectoryCacheLifetime" value to zero can resolve the issue.

Hope the below link can give you enough information.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686200.aspx

Hope this help