# Warning "File Does not Exist" moments after its creation

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing

We have a network shared folder on a Windows 2k8 R2 Server where an application generates a text file after the client app sends a command. Then the client must read this file and prompt an acknowledgment. That system works fine on every client we have, except for the ones with Windows 10. At those, the client app cannot open the file instantly - it takes about 5 seconds to be able to do it, while in Windows 7 and XP ones (yes, we still have these) it gets accessible as soon as it pops in the folder.

We have no antivirus, firewall, or other shenanigans that could be delaying the file creation and readability. Also, I must assume there is nothing particularly wrong server-side or at the network level, otherwise, the other client machines wouldn't be able to communicate with the application and that's not the case.

We also tested trying to manually open the generated file at the shared folder when it appears, and Windows 10 warns us that "this file does not exist. Would you like to create a new one?". If I say "no" and try again, then the file opens!

Since that system is time-sensitive - being that the sooner the client can read the response text file, the better - we are experiencing some confusion impairing. Does anybody have the slightest clue of what might be happening, like some file protocol difference between Windows client versions?

Comment: Answerers can enjoy https://superuser.com/questions/617046/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159220/ .